# What do I use as selector when styling dialog boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In CSS, I want to change the title bar color of a dialog box but it isn't working. This is the dialog box in html and the css.

```
     <div id="picture1Dialog" title = "Title">
     <p id="picture1Text"></p>        
     </div>  

     CSS
     #picture1Dialog.ui-dialog-titlebar{
     background-color: #f00;
     }
```

Comment: Where is the element with the class `ui-dialog-titlebar`?

Comment: @JoshCrozier It's created automatically by the jQuery UI Dialog widget.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I know. I've used jQuery UI in the past. But which element is it being added to?

Comment: It's not added to any of the original elements, it's a new element that the widget creates dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #picture1Dialog{
      background-color: #f00;
  }
```

Right click on your element and use the inspect element tool to get more details about your Styles rules. Also we could use more details on what this is:

```
 .ui-dialog-titlebar
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CVEqr/

Comment: This will set the background color of the entire dialog, not just the title bar.

Comment: `.ui-dialog-titlebar` is a class used by the jQuery UI Dialog widget.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector expects the `ui-dialog-titlebar` class to be added directly to the `pictureDialog` element. But the dialog is actually a DIV that wraps around your `pictureDialog` DIV, and the title bar is another DIV within it.

When you create the dialog, you can specify the class of that dialog, and then use that in your CSS:

```
$("#pictureDialog").dialog({
    dialogClass: 'picture-dialog',
    ...
});
```

Then you can use this CSS:

```
.picture-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the `ui-dialog-titlebar` in selector?

```
 .ui-dialog-titlebar{
     background-color: #f00;
 }
```